# Trying to switch bullet patterns in this game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a bullet-hell style game and I've *almost* got it to work except the opponent won't change from shooting one bullet pattern to another.

It's supposed to shoot 3 blue bullets 8 times, then switch to shooting 2 purple bullets 8 times. There's a sequence of patterns but I've only got two.

So it should iterate through each pattern every time the current pattern shoots a certain amount of times. When all the patterns are done it should stop shooting completely.

I've seen people try to make these but it's always java and I'm on python.

The code is very long but I can't cut it down any more. The original is in multiple files but I've put it into one script. It's virtually impossible to simplify.

```
import sys
import time
import itertools
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    #this sprite variable is a placeholder
    sprite = pygame.image.load("Sprites/player.png")

    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = Player.sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(445, 550))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 3
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= dist


class Spell:
    def __init__(self, bullet, pattern, speed, loop, tick_delay):
        self.bullet = bullet
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.speed = speed
        self.loop = loop
        self.tick_delay = tick_delay



class Opponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, sprite, sequence, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(425, 30))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)
        self.path = itertools.cycle((self.rect.topleft, ))
        self.next_point = pygame.Vector2(next(self.path))
        self.speed = 1
        self.ticks = 1000
        self.queue = []
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.spellno = 0
        self.currentspell = sequence[self.spellno]

    def update(self):
        #this function basically does most of the stuff in this class
        move = self.next_point - self.pos
        move_length = move.length()
        if move_length != 0:
            move.normalize_ip()
            move = move * self.speed
            self.pos += move

        #later on down the line i want to make the opponent sprite move
        if move.length() == 0 or move_length < self.speed:
            self.next_point = pygame.Vector2(next(self.path))

        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

        for i in range(0, self.currentspell.loop):
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.ticks > self.currentspell.tick_delay:
                self.ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                self.shoot()

        time_gone = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.ticks
        for bullet in self.queue:
            if bullet[0] <= time_gone:
                Bullet(self.rect.center, bullet[1], self.currentspell.bullet, sprites, bullets)

        self.queue = [bullet for bullet in self.queue if bullet[0] > time_gone]
        return

    def shoot(self):
        pattern = self.currentspell.pattern
        self.queue = pattern



class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, direction, image, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.direction = direction
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.direction
        self.rect.topleft = (self.pos.x, self.pos.y)
        if not screen.get_rect().colliderect(self.rect):
            self.kill()

sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

opponentgroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
mi1 = Spell(pygame.image.load("Sprites/lightblue-glowey.png"),(
            (0, pygame.Vector2(-0.5, 1) * 4),
            (0, pygame.Vector2(0, 1) * 4),
            (0, pygame.Vector2(0.5, 1) * 4)),
            10, 8, 340
            )

mi2 = Spell(pygame.image.load("Sprites/purple-glowey.png"),(
            (0, pygame.Vector2(1, 1) * 4),
            (0, pygame.Vector2(-1, 1) * 4)),
            4,  8, 340
            )

minty_spells = [mi1, mi2]

player = Player(sprites)
Minty = Opponent(pygame.image.load("Sprites/minty.png"), minty_spells, opponentgroup)

opponents = [Minty]

pygame.init()

SCREENWIDTH = 1000
SCREENHEIGHT = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT])

screen.fill((255, 123, 67))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 188), (50, 50, 900, 575), 0)
background = screen.copy()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

currentopponent = 0
def closegame():
    pygame.quit()
    return
def stage(opponent, background, bgm):
    currentopponent = opponent
    for spell in opponents[opponent].sequence:
        op = opponents[opponent]
        op.update()
        op.spellno += 1

def main():        
    running = True
    while running:   
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return

        # update all sprites
        sprites.update()
        sprites.add(opponents[currentopponent])
        # draw everything
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        stage(0, "", "") # "" means placeholder. i'm working on them

        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Original Code and assets on my GitHub: https://github.com/E-Lee-Za/Eleeza-Crafter-The-Game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working (and simplified) version of your code. The `loop` attribute of the current spell gets decremented every time when the bullets are created. When `loop` is 0, 
the `self.spellno` is incremented and the spell gets changed, otherwise if the `spellno` is `>= len(self.sequence)`, `self.currentspell` gets set to `None` so that it stops shooting (just add `if self.currentspell is not None` to the conditional statement).

```
import pygame


class Spell:

    def __init__(self, bullet, pattern, speed, loop, tick_delay):
        self.bullet = bullet
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.speed = speed
        self.loop = loop
        self.tick_delay = tick_delay


class Opponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, sprite, sequence, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(425, 30))
        self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.spellno = 0
        self.currentspell = sequence[self.spellno]

    def update(self):
        time_gone = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.start_time
        # Only create bullets if self.currentspell is not None.
        if self.currentspell is not None and time_gone > self.currentspell.tick_delay:
            self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            for bullet in self.currentspell.pattern:
                if bullet[0] <= time_gone:
                    Bullet(self.rect.center, bullet[1], self.currentspell.bullet, sprites, bullets)

            # Decrement the loop attribute of the current spell and
            # switch to the next spell when it's <= 0. When all spells
            # are done, set self.currentspell to None to stop shooting.
            self.currentspell.loop -= 1
            if self.currentspell.loop <= 0:
                self.spellno += 1
                if self.spellno >= len(self.sequence):
                    self.currentspell = None
                else:
                    self.currentspell = self.sequence[self.spellno]


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, direction, image, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.direction = direction
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.direction
        self.rect.topleft = (self.pos.x, self.pos.y)
        if not screen.get_rect().colliderect(self.rect):
            self.kill()


sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

opponentgroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
img = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
img.fill((0, 100, 200))
mi1 = Spell(
    img,
    ((0, pygame.Vector2(-0.5, 1) * 4), (0, pygame.Vector2(0, 1) * 4),
     (0, pygame.Vector2(0.5, 1) * 4)),
    10, 8, 340
    )
img2 = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
img2.fill((110, 0, 220))
mi2 = Spell(
    img2,
    ((0, pygame.Vector2(1, 1) * 4), (0, pygame.Vector2(-1, 1) * 4)),
    4, 8, 340
    )

minty_spells = [mi1, mi2]
img3 = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
img3.fill((220, 0, 200))
Minty = Opponent(img3, minty_spells, opponentgroup)
sprites.add(Minty)

pygame.init()
SCREENWIDTH = 1000
SCREENHEIGHT = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT])
screen.fill((255, 123, 67))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 188), (50, 50, 900, 575), 0)
background = screen.copy()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def main():
    while True:
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return

        sprites.update()

        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```